# how can i get all checked-in users for a particular place?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin

I need to implement logic for all checked-in facebook users details for a particular place(owned by me) inside my application(Not a facebook app).

Is facebook provide any facility to hit my app's url if any user checked-in my place?

or

is there any facebook api to get all checked-in users on an instance?

Thanks

Comment: not possible i think. you can only get the current users or his friends checkins and you will need permission for it. a place is basicly a page. see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ and the checkin connection.

Comment: @Rufinus, thanx for your quick reply,

Do you have some idea about Real time Updates, plz check following url, there is page object subscription for changes in various status as feed, friends, activities,movies, television, likes, checkins, location etc. Cannot i use this for the same.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: you can subscribe to ONE users checkins but this is far from knowing all checkins from various users at one place.